# TypeScript: dealing with `this` component properties which are reffering neither to state, nor to props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, class

Here are my interfaces:

```
export type alphaColorProcessing = (opacity: number) => string | string[];

export interface welcomeMapping {
  [key: string]: alphaColorProcessing | string;
}
export interface IPalette {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | alphaColorProcessing | welcomeMapping;
}
export interface IThemeContext {
  theme: string;
  palette: IPalette;
  setTheme?: (theme: string) => void;
}

export interface IThemeState extends IThemeContext {
  isDark: Boolean;
}

export interface IAppState {
  loading: boolean;
  themeState: IThemeState;
}

export interface IAppProps {
  setTheme?: (theme: string) => void;
}
```

I am using these in `App` component:

[image]

But I have the problem: while declaring a method on `this`, in constructor, as I understand it has nothing to do with `IAppState`. So my question is, how can I declare/use an interface for the methods which are refferring neither to State, nor to Props? I need for it for the methods/properties that I'm setting on `this` of the component.

`netInfoSubscription, setTheme` - is what I am interested in.

here's the code:

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{},IAppState>  {
  showedForce = false;

  showedBadIP = false;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setTheme = (theme:string) => {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        themeState: {
          ...state.themeState,
          theme,
          isDark: theme === 'dark',
          palette: Palette,
        },
      }));
    };
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      themeState: {
        theme: 'light',
        isDark: false,
        palette: Palette,
        setTheme: this.setTheme,
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.configure({
      reachabilityUrl: 'https://www.cisco.com/',
    });
    this.netInfoSubscription = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      handleConnectionStatus(state.isConnected);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { themeState, loading } = this.state;
    if (loading) return null;
    return (
      <Provider store={ Store }>
        <AppearanceProvider>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Root>
              <ThemeContext.Provider value={ themeState }>
                <Navigation />
                <FingerprintModal />
              </ThemeContext.Provider>
            </Root>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </AppearanceProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to show a typescript error message)

Comment: `setTheme` method can be defined outside the constructor

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two related things you've asked about: `setTheme` and `netInfoSubscription`.

You have several options:

### Method syntax

Your `setTheme` is a method, so you could write it as one, and use `bind` in the constructor:

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{},IAppState>  {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.setTheme = this.setTheme.bind(this);
        // ...
    }

    setTheme(theme: string) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

One advantage of that is that `setTheme` is on `App.prototype`, which is sometimes helpful for unit testing (it can be mocked).

That works for `setTheme`, but not for `netInfoSubscription`; you'll need one of the other options below for that.

### Property declarations (including the method)

You can write your `setTheme` as a property (and of course, `netInfoSubscription` is also a property):

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{},IAppState>  {
    setTheme = (theme: string) => {
        // ...
    };
    netInfoSubscription?: SubscriptionType;
    // Or:
    netInfoSubscription: SubscriptionType | null = null;
}
```

For `setTheme`, since that's an arrow function, it doesn't need binding. The context it closes over has `this` referring to the instance being constructed.

For `netInfoSubscription`, since we don't have a value for it during instance construction, there are two options:

- Use `?` to indicate that the property is optional.
- Use a union type with a value like `null` that we assign until/unless we have the subscription.

Note that either of those means that `netInfoSubscription` may be `undefined` (or `null`) anywhere in the code. For places where **you** know it's not (but TypeScript doesn't), you can grab it to a local constant and do an assertion:

```
someMethod() {
    // If we *know* (from the logic) that we have the subscription now
    const { netInfoSubscription } = this;
    assertNotNullish(netInfoSubscription);
    // ...here you can use `netInfoSubscription`'s value, and TypeScript will understand
    // that we now know it has one
    // ...
}
```

`assertNotNullish` is one of my standard utility functions, which looks like this:

```typescript
const assertNotNullish: <T>(value: T | undefined | null) => asserts value is T = (value) => {
    if (value == null) { // Checks `null` and `undefined`
        throw new Error(`Expected value to be non-nullish`);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBTATlAciDBXANrgSwgAsAuGAHgBUA+ACgDc5dslyqYAfGbMAEyQAzAmCR8uMMHlwBKGAF4a8RKigQYTFkhhEYHeTEbNWcxTADeAKBg2dgw5tYKDU-HPMwA9J5gBhYkjAANbqAAauuKHw-DChvALConyh1rZpUMQoIADukki5AKIoWSh0oQUAHgAOgVBiGsbaUCAwAEbaYOAAtBFExKEyANypNgC+lqPDlgLAuHAo2qCQsHwADOQAInB1EhGDXj4AgjBbOxnbMAC2cACebR3SlksQILhIAHS4IADmdGvvzQAkgBlADywKgKBEvxkQwOMCKJQANHobjVgcAoVUViAkBAwAByWBBTq5c6wAhQAnqTqwCKWaaBOYLGDPFYARk22203D28OOpyaxAu1zu7UkjwQyDQmBw+D6f3ZQye4Beb0+P0VAJAIPBkOhdFh+28qPRmII2JgJJy6kp1MkWAl+BgAQWDJmzMWqpWACYuTtuPEhCIxMajiduTByVdbvcePxg0lLFLVLL0NIFXwfcrnq8Pl9flntbqIVCwDC4SaqGikBiscTSbaqTTHUHEvVXUgGUA)

**Note:** You *could* just use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-), but I wouldn't. Using something like `assertNotNull` does a *runtime* check that what you're asserting is true. Using the non-null assertion operator doesn't, it just tells TypeScript to assume the assertion is true.

### An interface

You could define an interface:

```typescript
interface AppInstanceMembers {
    setTheme: (theme: string) => void;
    netInfoSubscription?: SubscriptionType;
    // ...
}
// ...
export default class App extends React.PureComponent<{},IAppState> & AppInstanceMembers {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.setTheme = (theme/* You don't have to repeat the type here*/) => {
            // ...
        };
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

That tells TypeScript to expect a `setTheme` (and possibly `netInfoSubscription`) on `App` (which you satisfy in the constructor). But it does mean you have to repeat some parts of `setTheme`.

As shown earlier, in places where **you** know from the logic (but TypeScript doesn't) that `netInfoSubscription` won't be nullish, you can use `assertNotNullish`.

Comment: Thank you so much, T.J.! By the way, I am Ukrainian, from Odesa - thank you for your support, appreciate it:)

Comment: @Olek - Awful what's going on there, I'm so sorry.

Comment: Yeah, REALLY awful stuff is going on right here...but we have great ally-countries, so I believe that madness will finish shortly:)

Comment: And T.J. also quick question, what if I want to just set a property on `this`, and I don't want to include it in State, and I don't have it in Props, and this is not a method, that i can just declare outside. For example `this.netInfoSubscription` - I got it in componentDidMount - how can I deal with it correctly?

Comment: @Olek - I've updated the answer to suggest things for `netInfoSubscription`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Easy

write function body **outside of the constructor**

Comment: Why is it a big deal when declaring a method in constructor?

Comment: 'this ' keyword in javascript works very differently inside function and blocks

Comment: @KunalGupta - Actually, `this` inside the constructor (after the call to `super`) and `this` where you're saying to create `setTheme` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Olek - It's just what TypeScript does and doesn't consider part of the type. TypeScript is declarative, so using property definition syntax (public class fields in JavaScript-speak) tells TypeScript the property exists, but just assigning to a property on `this` inside the constructor doesn't. Just a choice the TypeScript designers took.

Comment: how can I deal with `this.netInfoSubscription` that I have declared in a `didMount`?